# Export individual worksheets, except one to include as a common worksheet on all created workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I export some of the worksheets in my workbook to a new workbook saved with that name.

I don't want the "example" tab to generate its own individual file that is why I have <>"example".
I would like to include in the 20 files the example tab from the original document.

```vb
Sub copysheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim example As Worksheet
    Set example = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example")
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Menu" And ws.Name <> "Sheet insert" And ws.Name <> "Template" And ws.Name <> "Master Records" And ws.Name <> "Paste Here" And ws.Name <> "Example" Then
            ws.Copy
            wb_name = ws.Name
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
              "c:\output\" & DateString & wb_name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean remove this part? `And ws.Name <> "Example"`

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Perhaps someone else can make sense of it.

Comment: currently i have the code exporting 20 tabs and generating 20 new files named after their tab name. However i don't want the "example" tab to generate its own individual file that is why i have <>"example".  I would like to include in the 20 files the example tab from the original document. does that make sense braX can you assist?

Comment: perhaps you can show what you have tried first that would help people understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example").Copy , ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

Before this line:
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=.....`

This will copy the Worksheet `Example` into each new workbook you create and save in your loop.